# Building static nav in concrete5

Tags: menu, navigation, concrete5

I've inherited a site built with the CMS concrete5.  I'm just starting to dissect it but was hit with a wicked short deadline on a complete overhaul to the nav.  So, I want to build out a static nav and then go back when I have more time and integrate it with the auto-nav.  Does anybody have experience working with concrete5?  If so:

- Where would I drop my custom static nav?
- Is it possible to select it from the admin (so that the current one is still available if the client wants to switch back via the admin)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just dump your static nav in a HTML block, or make it part of a template.

your auto-nav could be stuck in a scrapbook so it doesn't go away.